# Gridview as a slide in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview, slideshow

I am using asp.net2.0 and c#.

I have to display data into the datalist/repeater/gridview. maximum 5-10 records. It should run in the bottom of the page and work similar like a slider in a horizontal way. Like when I click next, next 2 record will display.

Please help me,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Following link will help you.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=219&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

You need to use asp.net ajax tool kit slider extender for that.